# How can i fix this error: too many values to unpack (expected 4) for the code gievn below?

Tags: python

What is wrong with this code?

```
import pandas as pd

url1 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/users.csv'
url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/sessions.csv'
url3 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/products.csv'
url4 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/transactions.csv'

lst = [url1, url2, url3, url4]

def read_func(url):
    df = pd.read_csv(url)
    return df

for i in lst:
    users, sessions, products, transcation = read_func(i)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    users, sessions, products, transcation = read_func(i)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: `read_func()` takes one argument, and returns one object, a dataframe. You're trying to unpack that one object into 4 different variables for _each_ url because you're looping over your list

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url1='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/users.csv'
url2='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/sessions.csv'
url3='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/products.csv'
url4='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/transactions.csv'

lst=[url1, url2, url3, url4]

def read_func(lst):
    dfs = []
    for url in lst:
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(url))
    return dfs

users, sessions, products, transcation = read_func(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop is in the wrong place. You want to assign each dataframe to the respective variable, not each dataframe to all variables:

```
users, sessions, products, transcation = (read_func(url) for url in lst)
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you want to do? Use each csv as a df?

If that's the case, you are using an unpacking syntax where it should not be used.

`read_func(url)` is returning only one df and you are trying to unpack it to four variables.

Here i saved each df in a list then unpacked them to the variables you want.

```
data = []
for i in lst:
    data.append(read_func(i))

users, sessions, products, transaction = data
```